# Basic C# calculator exercise - "Use of unassigned local variable" error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm practicing switch statements with a very basic calculator script, but am confused why my final line which writes out the float variable *result* is receiving the error: "Use of unassigned local variable". And yes, there are much better ways to make a calculator involving loops, which I want to try next, but for now it's C# baby steps. Below is my code, thanks everyone!

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Greeting.

            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to the basic calculator");

            // Get first value.

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter the first value.");
            string firstValueAsText = Console.ReadLine ();
            float a = Convert.ToSingle (firstValueAsText);

            // Get second value.

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter the second value.");
            string secondValueAsText = Console.ReadLine ();
            float b = Convert.ToSingle (secondValueAsText);

            // Prompt operation.

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter '+', '-', '*', '/', '^'.");
            string operation = Console.ReadLine ();

            // Establishing the result and error variables for later.

            float result;
            string error = "ERROR";

            // Define switch operations.

            switch (operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = a + b;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = a - b;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = a * b;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = a / b;
                    break;
                case "^":
                    result = (float)Math.Pow(a, b);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine (error);
                    break;
            }

            // Print the result.

            Console.WriteLine (a + " " + operation + " " + b + " = " + result);
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at what happens if the user enters an invalid operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user enters an invalid operation it'll go into the `default:` flow. In that case `result` will never be assigned.

You can fix this by doing:

```
float result = 0;
```

or:

```
default:
    Console.WriteLine (error);
    result = 0;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing variable `result`, and it isn't assigned on all execution paths. You can overcome this compiler error either by initializing it when declared:

```
float result = 0;
```

...or by setting it in the `default` path of the switch:

```
default:
    result = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(error);
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you Shlomo -- makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If user input something unusual then it's going to `default` case, so you can handle this by something like

```
default:
  {
    Console.WriteLine (error);
    result = 0;
    break;
  }
```